# Could not rewrite the get variable url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I could rewrite the url `localhost/web1/index.php?page=home` to `localhost/web1/home`

But I couldn't rewrite the url `localhost/web1/index.php?page=property_details&pid=1008&aid=283` to `localhost/web1/property_details/1008/283`

Below is the code that I have used:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /web1/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+web1/?(?:index\.php)?\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: And what other URLs you have to need to be rewritten? Or are these the only two formats you encounter?

Comment: Yes these are the formats that I have used

Comment: The `RewriteCondition` does not match the second URL. Create an addition condition/rule that also checks for `pid` and `aid` in pretty much the same way as you check the `page` parameter.

Comment: I had tried by adding condition for second url but did not worked......

Comment: # new rules
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+web1/?(?:index\.php)?\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+web1/?(?:index\.php)?\?page=([^\s&]+)&pid=([^\s&]+)&aid=([^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1%2%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&pid=$2&aid=$3 [L,QSA]

Comment: please help me to add the condition for second url..